# can any function be called after the main's return 0 statement?

Tags: c++, c++11

the output of this code ,i  thought, should stop after first destructor.Because detructors are called after their enclosing braces.
therefore ,since the closing brace of first three destructors are after the return 0; statement,how do their destructors are called?

```
#include < iostream> 

using namespace std;

int val=0;

class abc
{

public :

  abc()
  {
    cout<<++val;
  }

  ~abc()     
  {     
    cout<<--val;    
  }

};

int main()
{
  abc a1,a2,a3;
  {
    abc a4;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

output:
12343210

why not :12343

Answer (score 5):

> Because detructors are called after their enclosing braces.

No, destructors of automatic objects are called when the program leaves their scope - whether that's by reaching the end of the block, or jumping out of it with `return`, `break`, `continue`, `goto` or `throw` (as long as the exception is handled).

Because of this, [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) allows us to manage dynamic resources safely and quite easily - as your example demonstrates, by destroying all the objects automatically. If that weren't the case, resource management would be next to impossible and no-one would try to write non-trivial programs in C++.

Caveats:

- If you terminate the program by calling a function (such as `std::exit`) rather than returning from `main`, then the stack won't unwind and no automatic variables will be destroyed.
- If an exception isn't caught before it leaves `main`, then it's unspecified whether the stack is unwound before the program terminates. On at least one popular compiler, it won't be.
- Using `std::longjmp` to leave a non-trivial automatic object's scope gives undefined behaviour; that C library function should be avoided in C++, unless you're doing something seriously funky.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors of `a1`, `a2`, `a3` (and `a4` of course) are called before the `main` finishes it execution since stack unwinding is a part of function execution process.

Answer (score 0):

In case of return from any function firstly all the local variables are destroyed. So the destructors for local objects are called actually before the return from the function.

Consider such a code:

```
class A
{
public:
    ~A()
    {
        throw bad_alloc();
    }
};

int f()
{
    A local_obj;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;

    try{
       a=f();
    }
    catch(...)
    {}

    std::cout<<a;

return 0;
}
```

The value of `a` variable in `main()` function will be 0, because function f() actually never returned anything.

Answer (score 0):

Destructor is called when object is destroyed. Return 0; is lat place, when programmer can call functions etc. After that, all operations are automatic, on example destroying objects.
The second thing: it can depend on placing definition in program. Main is function same as others - is places on stack frame. If you have any local variable, it is (**or should be!**) destroyed when calling return. Another situation is when you have definitions before main:

```
#include <iostream>
int something;
class SomeClass {...};
int main() {...}
```

This stuff is placed in other section which is destroyed **after** stack frame of main function. Read some informations about stack, heap and data segment.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

Answer (score 0):

Short answer :

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

is different from

```
int main() { std::abort(); }
```

Because abort will forcibly stop the execution before stack unwinding. return does not.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors are called as the object leaves scope, returning from a function even main will invoke this behavior.

However, calling exit(0) results in different behavior.

This

```
int main()
{
  abc a1,a2,a3;
  {
    abc a4;
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

results in

```
12343
```

Furthermore, if exit(0) is replaced with _Exit(0), then there is no output at all, but that is because the output buffer is not flushed, however, consider the following

```
~abc()
{
  cout<<--val;
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

...

```
abc a0;

int main()
{
   abc a1,a2,a3;
   {
      abc a4;
   }
   _Exit(0);
}
```

results in

```
123454
```

Here, unlike when exit() was used, not even the file scoped object a0 is destructed as the implementation has apparently used atexit() to register file scoped destructors.

> The atexit() function registers the function func to be called at program exit, whether via exit(3) or via return from the program's main().  Functions so registered are called in reverse order; no arguments are passed.